# How to enable "sleep after x minutes of inactivity" on Ubuntu Server 16.04 without third party software?

Tags: server, 16.04, power-management, amd-processor

So how do I know it's not working? Well on my MacPro, I set it to go to sleep after 15 minutes of inactivity. The monitor turns off and then the fans and all lights turns off. This doesn't happen on my newly setup Ubuntu Server 16.04 box.

so I was searching the net and it seem Ubuntu has built-in power management features. I found a folder called "/etc/pm/sleep.d".

[image]

Looking at the filename and actual contents, it doesn't seemed it has any thing to do with "sleep after x minutes of inactivity".

I've seen many discussions/Ubuntu wiki pages but they seemed to use third-party tools. But I somehow doubt Ubuntu on default install have no power management. This seems like a basic requirement for a modern OS.

Unless of course Ubuntu on default install DOES NOT provide "sleep after x minutes of inactivity" feature? And in that case, which 3rd-party is recommended? I'm seen pm-utils mentioned a lot. But I've also seen mentions of powernap.

This is a list of my basic requirements:

1. Host sleeps after x minutes of inactivity (CPU idle, no network traffic and etc)
2. wakes up due to various reasons (mouse/keyboard input, network traffic like I initiated an SSH connection on my Macbook, cron and etc)
3. slow down or speed up CPU (speedstep?) as needed

My setup:

AMD FM2 board with Realtek NIC. Video card is built-in into the CPU

Thanks a lot

Comment: It is highly unusual that a server would go to sleep, as it is there to serve, and do so quickly. You should find CPU frequency scaling to be functioning by default, as long as your BIOS settings allow it. I'm saying that your server should go into a minimal power state when idle by default, yet ramp up as required by heavy load demands.